# Setting a variable in Swift to something online

Tags: html, swift, variables, youtube

I'm working on a school project where we're taking our school's sports livestream, and putting it into an app.  The livestream is through youtube, therefore the v= part of the link changes for each livestream.  I have this code so far
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var liveStream: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let video = "7V-qltbXC8Y"
    var html = "<html><body><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(video)\" width=\"300\" height=\"300\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
    liveStream.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

This code works fine, as long as you put in the v= part of the link in (video.)
I want to know how I can set the constant video equal to something the live streamers post online.  In pseudocode

```
let video = String("\(Online input)")
```

Can someone please answer this, or provide some kind of alternative for what we're doing.  Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to wrap that in `String(...)` - `"\(Online input)"` is already a `String`.

Comment: Also, you're probably looking for `NSURLSession`. You'll hit a URL with that, parse the data with `NSString`, then place it in the formatted string.

Comment: Can you please explain how that works to me, and possibly walk me through it? I'm pretty new to programming.